# Decrypting audio/video on-the-fly to MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, video, encryption, media-player

I have been looking around for few days, but unable to get a clear answer on how to do it.

I have some encrypted audio/video files on my sdcard, which I would like to play which it will send to MediaPlayer, and start playing while decryption is working on the same time. It kinds of creates a buffer initially, and when it has enough initial data to start playing, MediaPlayer will start playing, and on background decrypting and keep sending the data over.

I looked around and most of the solution seem to point to having a localhttpserver, and then send the file to the server, and when it comes back, it will start playing the audio/video like a live stream. What I don't know is where does the decryption code comes in? In the server side? If so, in which part of it?

I have also seen this http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/ solution, that possibly able to solve it, but I can't seem to understand how that works. I know that it creates a localserver, but on the Cipher part, how does my own decryption comes in play?

```
private void myPlay(String path) {
    mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
    mServer.setCipher(myGetCipher());
    mServer.start();
    path = mServer.getURL(path);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.start();
}
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { // MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener interface
    mServer.stop();
}
```

As I am quite new to Android development, so do bear with me if I am unclear or anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also unable to play the encrypted video

Comment: This is not the best solution since you can`t watch the video unless you are online. It also makes you depend on the internet connection speed. Try to look for something do that Job locally on the device. If the files are small sized. You can do it once, but this will not work if you are dealing with big sized files.

Answer (score 0):

The decryption is done by the http server, if you provide it a Cipher.
Code something like this (you will have to add the exception catching somewhere):

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
private Cipher myGetCipher() {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("myPassword".getBytes(), "RC4"));
    return c
}
```

Comment: Hi @libeasy,I am following your postings from different places. Tried as below: But the encrypted video doesn't play with the same key and cipher. Pls. see my code below: (I am pasting my code as separate answer, this comment space is not enough.

Comment: For this kind of assistance, please use the contact mentioned on the site. Remember as well that saying that something doesn't work doesn't help much, instead provide a real report, with logcat and details about the device and the context.